# JFileChooser crashes - Java 7

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener, jfilechooser

I'm trying to make my program load a txt file with JFileChooser, but it doesn't seem to work. When I press the JButton, the console gives me a lot of errors. Here's the entire code so far:

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Sudoku extends JFrame{
    JPanel mainWindow = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttonWindow = new JPanel();
    JPanel sudokuArea = new JPanel();
    JButton load = new JButton("Load");
    JButton solve = new JButton("Solve");
    JTextArea sudokuGrid = new JTextArea();
    Field field = new Field();

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Sudoku();
  }

  public Sudoku(){
      super("SudokuSolver");
      setSize(200,300);
      setResizable(false);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      add(mainWindow);

      mainWindow.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      mainWindow.add(buttonWindow, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      mainWindow.add(sudokuArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      buttonWindow.add(load);
      buttonWindow.add(solve);

      sudokuArea.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      sudokuArea.add(sudokuGrid, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      sudokuGrid.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
      sudokuGrid.setEditable(false);
      sudokuGrid.append(field.toString());

      load.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                loader();
              }
            public void loader(){
                JFileChooser sumtin = new JFileChooser();
                if(sumtin.showOpenDialog() == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                {
                        File filer = sumtin.getSelectedFile();
                        field.fromFile(filer.getName());
                        sudokuGrid.setText(field.toString());
                        mainWindow.revalidate();
                        mainWindow.repaint();
                }
            } 
            } );
      setVisible(true);
  }
```

The field method is from another class called Field, but it's not really relevant (I think).

Here's what the console says:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Sudoku$1.loader(Sudoku.java:52)
        at Sudoku$1.actionPerformed(Sudoku.java:45)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm not really sure what to make of it, as I don't really know what it means. Any pointers?

EDIT: New errorcode after trying David Colers code:

```
    Sudoku.java:49: error: method showOpenDialog in class JFileChooser cannot be app
lied to given types;
                                if(sumtin.showOpenDialog() == JFileChooser.APPRO
VE_OPTION)
                                         ^
  required: Component
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Comment: which line in `loader` is line 52?

Comment: mainWindow.revalidate();

Comment: mainWindow is a JPanel where I put all my other components into.

Comment: Is `loader` getting called at some point when `mainWindow` is null?

Comment: Sudoku?  How are you handling multiple solutions?

Comment: Loader is only called when I press that button, and the button is in the mainWindow, so I don't think so. ----- I'm not handling multiple solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not handling the JFileChooser correctly for one thing.
EDIT: changed this keyword to null.

```
JFileChooser sumtin = new JFileChooser();
if(sumtin.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
        File filer = sumtin.getSelectedFile();
        field.fromFile(filer.getName());
        sudokuGrid.setText(field.toString());
        mainWindow.revalidate();
        mainWindow.repaint();
}
```

Comment: Just so people don't ask, yes you can have the showOpenDialog inside the if statement, makes it so you don't have to create another variable to handle the return.

Comment: This gives me another error.                                 if(sumtin.showOpenDialog() == JFileChooser.APPRO
VE_OPTION)
                                         ^
  required: Component
  found: no arguments

Comment: look at my code and look at what you just commented with.. put the "this" operator in it and also take out the space in the approve_option

Comment: I checked this code with my own program and the JFilechooser code works, if there is an error its with something else in the code then.

Comment: if you are still getting errors after the code change, please edit your original question and repost the error code

Comment: `this` won't work here, because it refers to the anonymous class created by `new ActionListener()`.

Comment: Sudoku.java:49: error: method showOpenDialog in class JFileChooser cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: then add in the super class your Sudoku class ie your superclass is Sudoku  then it would be Sudoku.this

Comment: @MathiasBøgebjerg You need to pass the reference of your `JFrame`. If you have a class that extends a `JFrame`, then you `ClassName.this` instead of just `this`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: what is your controlling class called? IE what Tom said your JFrame class

Comment: @MathiasBøgebjerg Use `sumtin.showOpenDialog(Sudoku.this)`.

Comment: @Tom Wow, null worked. But why? What's the point in doing that?

Comment: @DavidColer It does, but I guess it is safer to use the "real" reference, if possible :D.

Comment: Mathias please bump my post since it worked for you.

Comment: @DavidColer Done, you sir, are a good man. Btw, what's the difference between null and Sudoku.this here?

Comment: @MathiasBøgebjerg You will get this information [in the JavaDoc of `JFileChooser#showDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

you missed a few steps:

first create a filechooser

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
```

show it, and get the result

```
int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
```

And if the user has opened a file, you can get it and do what you want

```
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    ...
}
```